# Differences among different sieves encountered in sieve theory

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory

Are the sieve techniques used in understanding the twin prime conjecture or other number theoretical conjectures different from sieve theory used in primality testing or integer factorization? What are the differences between different sieve techniques? Could someone explain at a high level?

Comment: You might like to review [*Sieve Theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_theory) and [*Sieve_of_Eratosthenes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I checked it. Does not explain the differences well enough to get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a high level is.

I would say that the difference is operational. The sieves in factorization (quadratic sieve, number field sieve) are algorithmic techniques designed to optimize computations. The sieve in analytic number theory are theoretical constructs designed to optimize estimates of the number of elements in various sets.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. But by High level I meant what specific technical differences are there at a motivational level? Is the computational version just computer implementation of the theoretical constructs? things like that.

Comment: @Arul: are you looking for us to provide the algorithms for the sieve of twin prime and compare that to factorization methods like the quadratic sieve and general number field sieve? Those two groups of items are different and there are entire books written on Sieve Methods. Regards

Comment: Amzoti: I know this question is probably naive. But hankyou for the comment What is difference between the sieve in twin prime or the Selberg sieve and say QS and GNS? What pattern do the theoretical constructs look for that cannot be applied to the practical ones and vice versa?

Comment: I think comparing the Selberg sieve and the quadratic sieve is a bit like comparing the multiplication table and the coffee table. Yes, they have a word in common, and if you trace things back far enough there's a reason why they use the same word, but beyond that....

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is what I wanted to know:) beyond the name if there is anything more comparable? Wiki itself says integer factroization sieves are different. May be there is a better way to put the question.